# Display data on same page or separate page?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm working on my first mobile app. I'm getting input from the User and having them click a button before retrieving data into a dataset. All that is working well but getting the data displayed has stopped me in my tracks. Can/Should I display it in the same page or create a 2nd one? How do I call a second page from my c# code? I don't know best practices for Xamarin and mobile so any assistance or direction would be helpful.

Comment: Whether to use 1 page or 2 is a design decision that is up to you.  I personally would weigh whether or not all of the data easily fits onto one page.  As far as navigating to a 2nd page, there are numerous examples, samples and walkthroughs on Xamarin's site that explain navigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this and reasons for doing it, it all depends on your app. I assume you're not using xamarin forms, so I'll give default android/iOS answers.

**Can/Should I display it in the same page?**

- If you're making the usual search control it helps displaying the search results in the same page as the one you are typing in.
- If you have a list of items, where selecting one shows more details, then the usual way of doing it is to navigate to a new page that displays the information. So you'll have to create another page.
- There are multiple ways of doing this it all depends on your app.

**How do I call a second page from my c# code?**

You don't call the second page from your first page, you rather launch the page and pass the information you want.

**Android:**  You'll create a new Activity with it's layout file and use an intent to launch the activity from your Action (clicking a button in your case).

You can use [this tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/hello,android_multiscreen/hello,android_multiscreen_quickstart/) to get up to speed with miltiscreen Xamarin applications for android. Your code should look similar to the following.

```
Button yourButton = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.YourButtonId);
yourButton.Click += (sender, e) =>
{
  var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(SecondActivity));
  StartActivity(intent);
};
```

To pass information to the second page you can use one of the      intent.PutExtra() methods. Similar to

```
intent.PutStringArrayListExtra("YourKey", myList);
```

Which passes a list to the launching activity through the intent, storing the value under YourKey. In your SecondActivity you can get the data from your intent using

```
intent.GetExtra("YourKey")
```

**iOS:** Not much code involved so I'll list the steps to do this briefly. You can use [this tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/hello,_iOS_multiscreen/hello,_iOS_multiscreen_quickstart/) to get started with multiscreen iOS applications.

1. You'll create a new controller in your Main storyboard, using Interface Builder or Xamarin Studio.
2. On your first view, place your button.
3. press Ctrl and drag it to the new ViewController. On releasing your click select Show (push) segue.
4. In your FirstViewController override prepareForSegue and set the data you want to use in your SecondViewController.

Something like below.

```
public override void PrepareForSegue (UIStoryboardSegue segue, NSObject sender)
  {
    base.PrepareForSegue (segue, sender);

    // set the View Controller that’s powering the screen we’re
    // transitioning to

    var secondViewController = segue.DestinationViewController as SecondViewController;

    secondViewController.YourData = "Your data you want to pass over";
 }
```

Let me know if this answers your question. Goodluck.

Comment: We were able to launch a 2nd page ... so Thanks for the help with that. We decided it would be better to have everything on 1 page so we're trying to use a GridLayout to display the data. Can a GridLayout display multiple rows/columns? My data source is a datatable with multiple rows but it only displays the last row's data. Perhaps a GridLayout isn't the best option to view the data, I've tried a GridView too but didn't have much luck with it.

Comment: @RoMiSh Since the answer helped for what your question was can you please mark it as correct for people dealing with the problem in the future. And on GridLayout and GridView it's meant to display rows/colums, It's probably displaying the last page because you are overwriting the same column and row with the newer data.